# How to derive the Christoffel symbols from the embeding view?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I encountered a statement in a book:

If we define the manifold as embedded in a higher-dimensional Euclidian space, as a hypersurface $X(x)$, then the metric is given by 
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu X\cdot \partial_\nu X$$
and the Christoffel symbols are easily derived to be 
$$\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda}=\partial^\mu X\cdot \partial_\nu\partial_\lambda X=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\rho}(\partial_\nu g_{\rho\lambda}+\partial_\lambda g_{\rho\nu}-\partial_\rho g_{\nu\lambda}).$$

Now I can not see how to derive $\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda}=\partial^\mu X\cdot \partial_\nu\partial_\lambda X$ from the point of view of embedding. Can someone explain it? Thank you very much.

Comment: $\partial^\mu$ seems to be a shortcut for $g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}$. The rest is pretty standard, one can derive the Levi-Civita-equation (for the Christoffel symbols in terms of the metric) from it.

Comment: @ccorn, I know we can express $\Gamma$ by metric components from the second equation. But what I want to know is how to derive the second equation from the hypersurface.

Comment: Well, what do you get when you plug the expression for $g_{\mu\nu}$ in the Levi-Civita equation? (I suppose, the latter has originally been derived from the former though, not vice versa, as we do here.)

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are after. What's your *current* definition for the Christoffel symbols?

Comment: @ccornl, I changed my post. Actually now it is the real form stated by the book (pp.57 of <Conformal Field Theory> by Francessco etc.)

Comment: Hmm, I still cannot see what actually is unclear (probably because I learned things from the embedded view first)

Comment: I mean, one just plugs in $g_{\rho\nu}=\partial_\rho X\cdot\partial_\nu X$ etc (but keeps $g^{\mu\rho}$ unreplaced), applies the product rule and uses commutativity of the inner product and of partial derivation. Where is the problem?

Comment: What identity for the Christoffel symbols are you willing to accept as a starting point? If it's the Levi-Civita equation, things are easy -- basically a matter of plugging in and applying the usual simplifications. If it's, say, *projections of partially derived basis vectors*, then we'll have to identify the basis vectors (as the $\partial_\mu X$), and the rest is again easy. But it all begins with what you *know* about the ${\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\lambda}$, or rather, what you are willing to accept as a starting point.

Comment: Zee's gravity book?

Comment: @ccorn Sorry for responding you so late. What I am not clear is $\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda}=\partial^\mu X\cdot \partial_\nu\partial_\lambda X$. I mean, from the start point that $\Gamma$ represents the parallel transfer, how can we obtain this equation?

Comment: @0celo7 <Conformal Field Theory> by Francessco etc.